# Removing Applications Menu Listing with CLI command

Tags: unity, command-line, launcher

I am trying to make an application installer item in the menu. Where once you click on it, it executes the command to install the program. I can use apt-get for this and a custom launcher.

However, after the application is installed, how can I make it so that it automatically removes the "Installer Launcher" once the app is installed?

Forgive me if I was unclear, I was unsure how to state my question.

PS: I am using the xfce(xubuntu) environment.

Comment: The installer-launcher could delete itself once the application is installed. Or did you want to do something else ?

Comment: You can always have a menu item which points to a script which runs the application if available and attempts to install it otherwise.

Comment: thom, yes, I wanted the installer-launcher to delete itself after the application is installed. I'm just not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out what launchers something has installed by running:

```
dpkg -L <package> | grep -E "^/usr.*share.*desktop\$"
```

That will list the files. You can either delete those (I'm not sure I would) or rename them to something else (like sticking a `.disabled` on the end). Here's how I'd do the second:

```
dpkg -L <package> | grep -E "^/usr.*share.*desktop\$" | sudo xargs -I% mv "%" "%.disbaled"
```